# USB Pendrive not mounting after formating

Tags: command-line, mount, usb-drive, format

I formatted my USB pendrive, and now it is not mounting.

I did the slow method of format (replacing data with zeroes).

Comment: Zeroing out is not exactly the right way to make it mount. You need to create a partition table and a filesystem.

Answer (score 6):

That's to be expected.

By zeroing it out, **you've overwritten the partition table and filesystem.**

You need to use `Gparted` or the Included "Disks" program to create a new partition table and filesystem.

Comment: Quite so, but imho, destruction is permanent, often unexpected, tragic and dramatic. What we have here is neither of these.

Comment: @mikewhatever - Edited.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem seems to be resolved now. What happened was, the formatting took almost an hour. I went into disk management and saw the process continuing. It's working fine now, thanks for your answer!